# R paste time difference with unit (sec, min etc)

Tags: r

In R I want to get the timing in a character string keeping the unit (e.g., if it is sec or min). Please see example code below.

```
T1 <- Sys.time()

T2 <- Sys.time()
duration <- T2-T1

# Looking at duration show unit:
duration

time_description <- paste("it took: ", round(duration, 2), sep="", col="")

# However int time description the unit is removed
time_description
```

Preferably without using additional packages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `units` to extract the unit from `difftime` object.

```
time_description <- sprintf('it took %.2f %s', duration, units(duration))
time_description
#[1] "it took 0.39 secs"
```